# How to check if an object is already existing or not in mongodb array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am making a simple api which has like document of each post.The like post has array of object of likes of that post.I want to like object into likes only if the document is not exist and if exist remove the object from likes array.I have use **element match** operator
but it does not work.How can I achieve this.Thanks in advance.

The code is

```
    router.post("/like",(req,res)=>{
        likeModel.find({ postId: req.body.postId }, async (err, doc) => {
    console.log(req.body.postId)
    console.log(doc.length+"s ");
    if (!doc.length) {
      const like = new likeModel({
        postId: req.body.postId,
        likes: [
          {
            userId: userId,
            isNotified: isNotified,
          },
        ],
      });
      await like.save((err, doc) => {
        if (err) res.json({ "message": "error" });
        else res.json(doc);
      });
    }
    if (err) {
      res.json({ "message": "error"});
    } 
       else{
 likeModel.find({
            postId:req.body.postId,
            likes:{
                $elemMatch:{
                    userId:req.body.userId
                }
            }
        },(err,doc)=>{
            console.log(doc.length)
            if(err){
                res.json({"message":"error"})
            }
            else if(!doc.length){
                likeModel.updateOne(
                    { _Id: req.body.postId },
                    {
                      $push: {
                        likes:req.body.likes
                      },
                    },
                    (err, doc) => {
                      if (err) res.json({ "message": "err" });
                      else res.json(doc);
                    }
                  );
            }
            else{
                likeModel.updateOne({
                    postId:req.body.postId
                },{
                    "$pull":{
                        "likes":{
                            "userId":req.body.userId
                        }
                    }
                },(err,doc)=>{
                    if(err){
                        res.json({"message":err})
                    }
                    else{
                        res.json(doc)
                    }
                }
                )
            }
}
        })
    })
```

The document looks like

```
[
    {
        "_id": "62f8556861c9b1029e7a07b8",
        "postId": "62f5fb7d74033aeac1e06399",
        "likes": [
            {
                "userId": "62f5d6bee2310e3c71e10e36",
                "isNotified": true,
                "_id": "62f8556861c9b1029e7a07b9"
            },
            {
                "userId": "62f5d9c2b30ecc8ca84c0242",
                "isNotified": true,
                "_id": "62f865ed2a055ef17214a6ea"
            },
            {
                "userId": "62f5d9c2b30ecc8ca84c0242",
                "isNotified": true,
                "_id": "62f866192a055ef17214a6f1"
            },
            {
                "userId": "62f5d9c2b30ecc8ca84c0242",
                "isNotified": true,
                "_id": "62f8668c5ca6a649fc89cc3b"
            },
    

        {
                    "userId": "62f5d9c2b30ecc8ca84c0242",
                    "isNotified": true,
                    "_id": "62f866b3c2041b73ea8d9d8a"
                },
                {
                    "userId": "62f5d9c2b30ecc8ca84c0242",
                    "isNotified": true,
                    "_id": "62f867b6545168c7cd377b17"
                },
                {
                    "userId": "62f5d9c2b30ecc8ca84c0242",
                    "isNotified": true,
                    "_id": "62f868cf3255b839e1ca047b"
                }
            ],
            "__v": 0
        },
{
        "_id": "62f866192a055ef17214a6ed",
        "postId": "62f5fb7e74033aeac1e0639d",
        "likes": [
            {
                "userId": "62f5d9c2b30ecc8ca84c0242",
                "isNotified": true,
                "_id": "62f866192a055ef17214a6ee"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: simply use `{ "likes.userId": req.body.userId }` [check it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MgoKYz1SYSK)

Comment: not working....

Comment: you sure you are passing the right id in `req.body.userId`? and what do you get in `console.log(doc.length)` ?

Comment: yes,I am making post request not get...

Comment: I have  solve the issue. Infact userId is in array of object and was accessing it without mapping.After mapping I got the result.